# De hash a password_hash with a cost

Tags: php, password-hash

If I hash for example a password 20 times with a cost:

```
$Pass1=password_hash($Pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, ['cost' => 20])
```

And then I store it in my database, how can I let user login on my website, if the `password_verify()` from what i know , de hash the password "once a time"?

Did I need to do a `password_verify ($password,$storedPassword)` 20 times?
Or is there an easier way to do it? I saw about a password_needs_rehash, I have already tried to use it and it didn't work.

Comment: Hashing a password multiple times does not increase security. The normal approach to checking whether a text is the previously saved password is to follow the same transformation process as for the original (i.e. in this case to hash the incoming text 20 times and compare against the previously saved hash).

Comment: You hash the password with a cost factor of 20, the cost factor is actually stored in the hash itself, so password_verify can see both the hash algorithm and the cost factor and use those to validate the supplied password. Just use it as in the OP, it will take care of the rest.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, after a bit of time

```
$Pass1=password_hash($Pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, ['cost' => 20]);
password_verify($PasswordInputByUser, $Pass1);
```

So simple!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$Pass = 'greatPassword1';
$Pass1 = password_hash( $Pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, ['cost' => 12] );
echo $Pass1;
```

> $Pass1 is $2y$12$cnxAUfdMyA67QmsCW.x2aOVxvSyLPb/idLgklfAJOG5BPDcNlV1ba

In the beginning of the hashed password you see $2y$12$, and you'll see all of the passwords you create will have the same thing in the beginning. This is how PHP knows the algorithm and cost. So when you want to verify the password is the same, all you have to do is:

```
$verified = password_verify('greatPassword1', $Pass1);
// True

$verified = password_verify('wrongPassword1', $Pass1);
// False
```

If you're using a cost of 20 you will most likely see $2y$20$ in the beginning of the hashed password. My PHP was not set up to allow more than 30 seconds execution time, so I changed to a lower cost value.